# Decoding parquet min/max statistics for Decimal type

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

I have created a parquet file with a decimal column type `pa.decimal128(12, 4)` using pyarrow. After I read the file and access its metadata I get the following output:

```
<pyarrow._parquet.ColumnChunkMetaData object at 0x7f4752644310>
  file_offset: 26077
  file_path: 
  physical_type: FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY
  num_values: 3061
  path_in_schema: Price
  is_stats_set: True
  statistics:
    <pyarrow._parquet.Statistics object at 0x7f4752644360>
      has_min_max: True
      min: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x9b\xdc'
      max: b'\x00\x00w5\x93\x9c'
      null_count: 0
      distinct_count: 0
      num_values: 3061
      physical_type: FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY
      logical_type: Decimal(precision=12, scale=4)
      converted_type (legacy): DECIMAL
  compression: SNAPPY
  encodings: ('PLAIN_DICTIONARY', 'PLAIN', 'RLE')
  has_dictionary_page: True
  dictionary_page_offset: 22555
  data_page_offset: 23225
  total_compressed_size: 3522
  total_uncompressed_size: 3980
```

As you can see the min/max values are actually byte objects.
How would I decode these to actual decimal values?

I tried casting it with

```
pc.cast(statistics.max, pa.decimal128(12, 4))
```

but got the following error message instead

> pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: Unsupported cast from binary to decimal using function cast_decimal

Comment: For decimal128 you'd expect to have 16 bytes, but here you only have 6. Maybe they've been truncated. In which case try `int.from_bytes(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x9b\xdc', 'big') / 1_000)`

Comment: BTW, there is an [open feature request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-7350) for decoding these to a better type.

Answer (score 1):

The statistics are based on the physical type and not the logical type.  For `Decimal(precision=12, scale=4)` the physical type is `FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY` which is what the min and max are.  Unfortunately, in order to convert back to a decimal, you'll need to know how Arrow is encoding to a fixed length byte array.

It first determines how many bytes are needed based on the precision.  You won't need to reverse engineer this part.  It then converts to big endian, truncates down to the needed bytes and writes them.  So this should allow you to convert back.

```
def pad(b):
  # Left pad 0 or 1 based on leading digit (2's complement rules)
  if b[-1] & 128 == 0:
    return b.ljust(16, b'\x00')
  else:
    return b.ljust(16, b'\xff')

def to_pyarrow_bytes(b):
  # converts from big-endian (parquet's repr) to little endian (arrow's repr)
  # and then pads to 16 bytes
  return pad(b[::-1])

def decode_stats_decimal(b):
  pyarrow_bytes = to_pyarrow_bytes(b)
  arr = pa.Array.from_buffers(dtype, 1, [None, pa.py_buffer(pyarrow_bytes)], 0)
  return arr[0].as_py()

decode_stats_decimal(statistics.max)
# Decimal('199999.9900')
decode_stats_decimal(statistics.min)
# Decimal('3.9900')
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Sometimes I can see decoded min/max values that are different from the actual column min/max. In this particular example, the minimum is 0.0 but statistics yields me 3.99.

Comment: That seems wrong and I'm able to reproduce this.  I've filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-12054

Comment: In regards to wrong min/max values to summarize here: This is known bug when writing decimal types PARQUET-1655. This should now be fixed on the master branch and the next release (pyarrow 4.0 Expected April 2021) will contain the fix.